# Foreach loop is not displaying data

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, model-view-controller

I tried to post data with Jquery and I want to print the result in table manner. I debug this code and saw that all code is working fine and data is coming to the view page, but I don't know why the foreach loop is not displaying the data on web. Here is my code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ByAgentName(int BranchId, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {
      ViewReportViewModel model = new ViewReportViewModel();
      var result = (from tickassign in db.TicketsAssignmets
                    join usercounter in db.UserCounterAssignments on tickassign.AssignedUserId equals usercounter.UserId
                    join user in db.Users on tickassign.AssignedUserId equals user.Id
                    join counter in db.Counters on usercounter.CounterId equals counter.Id
                    join counterser in db.CounterServices on counter.Id equals counterser.CounterId
                    join clientser in db.ClientServices on counterser.ServiceId equals clientser.Id
                    join serviceCat in db.ServiceCategories on clientser.CategoryId equals serviceCat.Id
                    where (tickassign.CreatedOn >= StartDate) && (tickassign.CreatedOn <= EndDate) && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(usercounter.CreatedOn) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(tickassign.CreatedOn))
                    && (counter.BranchId == BranchId) && (clientser.BranchId == BranchId)
                    orderby tickassign.CreatedOn descending
                    select new ReportResult
                    {
                      Date = tickassign.CreatedOn,
                      CounterId = counter.Id,
                      AgentId = user.Id,
                      CounterName = counter.Name,
                      AgentName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName,
                      ServiceCat = serviceCat.Name,
                      ServiceCatId = serviceCat.Id,
                      ServiceId = clientser.Id,
                      ServiceName = clientser.Name,
                      TotalService = db.TicketsAssignmets.Where(x => x.AssignedUserId == usercounter.UserId && x.StartDateTime == tickassign.StartDateTime && (x.AssignStatus == "Complete" || x.AssignStatus == "Decline")).Count()
                    }).ToList();
      model.StartDate = StartDate;
      model.EndDate = EndDate;
      model.Branch = BranchId;
      model.Results = result;
      BindCollection();
      return View(model);
```

And the View Section

```
@model App.Data.ViewModels.ViewReportViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Agent Report";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PrivateLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading ">
    <b>
      Agent Report
    </b>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.Label("Branch", new { @class = "col-sm-1 control-label" })
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DropDownList("BranchId", null, "------Select Branch------", new { @class = "form-control select-sm", @id = "ddlClientBranch" })
          </div>
          @Html.Label("From Date", new { @class = "col-sm-1 control-label" })
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="input-group date">
              <input type="text" id="fromDate" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="From Date" name="fromD" style="padding: 10px;">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          @Html.Label("To Date", new { @class = "col-sm-1 control-label" })
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="input-group date">
              <input type="text" id="ToDate" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="To Date" name="toD" style="padding: 10px;">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2 ">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block pull-right" value="Search" onclick="GetResult();" style="max-width: 50%;" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @*@if (Model.Results.Count != 0)
  {*@
    <div id="AgentReport" style="margin-top:4%">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="font-weight:bold">
          Search Result
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="text-align:center">Agent Name</th>
              <th style="text-align:center">Date</th>
              <th style="text-align:center">Counter Name</th>
              <th style="text-align:center">Service</th>
              <th style="text-align:center">Total Job Done</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Results)
            {
              <tr>
                <td>@item.AgentName</td>
                <td>@item.Date</td>
                <td>@item.CounterName</td>
                <td>@item.ServiceName</td>
                <td>@item.TotalService</td>
              </tr>
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

the scrip section for post data

```
@section scripts{
  @Scripts.Render("~/Content/DateTimePicker/JS/jquery.timepicker.js");
  <script>
    $('#ddlClientBranch').select2({
      placeholder: "-----Select Branch-----",
      allowClear: true
    });

    $('#fromDate').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', 'today');
    $('#fromDate').datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      autoClose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
    });

    $('#ToDate').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', 'today');
    $('#ToDate').datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      autoClose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
    });

    $(".input-group.date").datepicker({
      format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      startDate: '01/01/2000',
    });

    function GetResult() {
      var ClientBranch = $('#ddlClientBranch').val();
      var FromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
      var Todate = $('#ToDate').val();

      if (ClientBranch == null || ClientBranch == "0" || ClientBranch == "-----Select Branch-----") {
        toasterErrorMessage("Please Select Branch");
      }
      else if (FromDate == "") {
        toasterErrorMessage("Please Select From Date");

      }

      else if (Todate == "") {
        toasterErrorMessage("Please Select To Date");

      }

      else {
        debugger
        $.ajax({
          url: "/Client/ViewReport/ByAgentName?BranchId=" + ClientBranch + "&StartDate=" + FromDate + "&EndDate=" + Todate,
          type: "Post"

        })
      }
    }
  </script>
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this at all? Check that `Results` actually contains some entities? There's no way anyone can accurately debug this without knowing what data is in your database, or what it returns.

Comment: Did you check if there address any items in `model.Results`?

Comment: Yes Results is Actually Contails entity and in debug mode the foreach loop iterate as many time as the Model.results.count value.

Comment: Do you want My full view code to see how i am sending the value to the controller?

Comment: @Naruto What does the method `BindCollection();` do? You call the before you send the model to your view. Maybe it is doing something that it is not supposed to do.

Comment: @RahulSharma BindCollection() is for dropdown list  and even if i commented it, but problem is still same

Comment: @Naruto Can you post your full code for `View`? Also during debugging, please confirm if `model.Results = result;` contains values.

Comment: @Rahul sharma Thanks for reply here is my full view code

Comment: how could i send you full code because it is exceed the word limit in the comment section

Comment: @Naruto In this line: `model.Results = result;` , what values do you receive for `model.Results` only during debugging. Your `View` code looks fine. Just for giggles, do you see the values in your view when you set your layout to null? `Layout = "null"`

Comment: show your Model.Results data .and when you are calling your ByAgentName method ? is it as ajax call or which is return View when the particular page loads ?